# Writing extended piece of text using paste() in R

Tags: r, regex, text, char, paste

I'm trying to `paste` all the following `paste0`s as one connected piece of text. But I also need to have each on a separate line, one after the other, like:

`"CI=~Q1+Q2+Q3+Q4+Q5+Q6
ESC=~Q7+Q8+Q9+Q10+Q11+Q12
ICp=~Q13+Q14+Q15+Q16+Q17+Q18
.
.
. "`

I tried creating the object `model` to achieve my goal. All works fine EXCEPT that each `paste0` is not on a separate line.

Is there a fix for that in BASE R?

```
CI <- paste0("CI=~", paste0("Q", 1:6, collapse = "+"))

ESC <- paste0("ESC=~", paste0("Q", 7:12, collapse = "+"))

ICp <- paste0("ICp=~", paste0("Q", 13:18, collapse = "+"))

 LC <- paste0("LC=~", paste0("Q", 19:24, collapse = "+"))

 CR <- paste0("CR=~", paste0("Q", 25:30, collapse = "+"))

 ASE <- paste0("ASE=~", paste0("Q", 31:36, collapse = "+"))

 SOM <- paste0("SOM=~", paste0("Q", 37:42, collapse = "+"))

 UP <- paste0("UP=~", paste0("Q", 43:48, collapse = "+"))

 VL <- paste0("VL=~", paste0("Q", 49:54, collapse = "+"))

 model <- paste(CI, ESC, ICp, LC, CR, ASE, SOM, UP, VL, sep = "\n")
```

Comment: If it is to create a vector, you just need `c(CI, ESC, ICp, ..)`

Comment: Can you show the expected output?  Are these columns of a dataset?

Comment: The `sep="\n"` with `cat` would print exactly what you wanted.  Not sure about the goal though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `cat` if it is just to `print`

```
cat(paste(CI, ESC, ICp, LC, CR, ASE, SOM, UP, VL, sep = "\n"), '\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

You are sooo close: Use the `collapse` argument of `paste0` but pass it a vector:

```
model <- paste0(c(CI, ESC, ICp, LC, CR, ASE, SOM, UP, VL), collapse = "\n")

cat(model)

CI=~Q1+Q2+Q3+Q4+Q5+Q6
ESC=~Q7+Q8+Q9+Q10+Q11+Q12
ICp=~Q13+Q14+Q15+Q16+Q17+Q18
LC=~Q19+Q20+Q21+Q22+Q23+Q24
CR=~Q25+Q26+Q27+Q28+Q29+Q30
ASE=~Q31+Q32+Q33+Q34+Q35+Q36
SOM=~Q37+Q38+Q39+Q40+Q41+Q42
UP=~Q43+Q44+Q45+Q46+Q47+Q48
VL=~Q49+Q50+Q51+Q52+Q53+Q54
```

## Edit:

Just to not confuse you, `paste` instead of `paste0` works also:

```
model <- paste0(c(CI, ESC, ICp, LC, CR, ASE, SOM, UP, VL), collapse = "\n")
```

Also gives the desired result